# Jquery autosuggest google maps - Load on selection

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

At the moment, the Google map code works like this:

When you start typing in the input box it loads a list of suggestions. Then when you click on one of these options from the list, it puts it into the input box. However, THEN you still have to click find to load up the result.

I want to have it so when you click on an option from the autosuggest list, it automatically loads the result, without having to click "find" afterwards.

This is the code I am working with. I hope I explained this question correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/BxG9H/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this jsfiddle. You have to listen to the 'select' event of the autocomplete widget.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/

edit

```
$(function() {
    $(PostCodeid).autocomplete({
        //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values


        // ONLY THIS PART :)
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          // first SET value before trigger click event
          $(this).val($(ui.item).attr('value'));
          $('#findbutton').click();
        },


        source: function(request, response) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': request.term
            }, function(results, status) {
                response($.map(results, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.formatted_address,
                        value: item.formatted_address
                    };
                }));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you! Would you be kind enough to tell me where you added the event code? All I can find is the "findbutton" click event.

Comment: Sorry to remove as answer but it doesnt work. If you type in "Kent" then you get three options. If you click on the second option, "Kent, UK" it loads up the option for the first autosuggest option!